# Android: trouble retrieving playlists from Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, playlist, mediastore

I have an Android application that reads playlists stored on a phone:

```
playlistCursorExt = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME + " ASC");
```

This works fine on most phones, but not on Samsung Galaxy phones. Whatever playlists I create through the default music player, the managedQuery returns null.

Is there a special way to retrieve playlists from Samsung Galaxy phones?

Comment: I have the same problem. It might be something to do with the Samsung's internal storage being mounted as external storage, but I haven't found a work around yet. Both for external_content_uri and internal_content_uri I get no playlists...

Comment: I figured out that Samsung uses a custom media player application on their phones. Presumably, the application stores the playlists in a database only accessible to the application itself.
Unless the application has a contentprovider for the DB, I don't think there is a way to access the playlists created by their music app.